# How to disable CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH in CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: cmake, fedora, rpm, rhel, cpack

I am still a `CMake` newbie (started learning 3 days ago). In my current `CMakeLists.txt`, I have the following `set` directives:

```
[...]
SET(CPACK_GENERATOR "RPM")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "3")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "3")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH "svn")
SET(CPACK_SYSTEM_NAME "0.el6.x86_64")
[...]
```

Once I run `make package`, I got a `libcxx-3.3.svn-0.el6.x86_64.rpm`.

But IMHO this is "cheating".

According to http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:NamingGuidelines#Package_Naming_and_Versioning_Guidelines, ideally I should be able to generate a `libcxx-3.3-0.el6.x86_64.rpm` instead.  But this demands that `CPack` not to show the `CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH`.

Nevertheless, according to my trial results, it doesn't seem to be feasible. I would appreciate a hint as to how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try setting CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME (without the extension) to the desired name? This is provided so that you can define your own package naming scheme if the default does not suit your needs. See http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:CPackConfiguration for more details on key CPack variables and what they do.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. `CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME` by default has the value `${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME}-${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION}-${CPACK_SYSTEM_NAME}`, so I guess all I have to do is to reset `CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION` instead?  `CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION` is built from `CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR`, `CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR`, and `CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH`, AFAICT.

Comment: Yeah. Indeed, using the `CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME` is the only way to do it. Tested with `cmake` 2.8.8. Attempting to set `CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION` does not seem to take any effect. x-(

Comment: You either accept the hardwired logic, or apply your own by manipulating the variable provided. I think this is a reasonably approach, that variable is provided to allow for adjustment of the package file name.